# Why does Safari not wrap second div?

Tags: css, web, safari, frontend, flexbox

I have 2 `div` in another `div`. Both are flex and both have a `min-width`. In Chrome and Firefox, the second one wraps because its `min-width` forces it, but Safari doesn't warp it as long as those two inner `div` are flex.

Here is an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/0du7yn1h/1/):

HTML

```
<div class="a">
    <div class="b"></div><div class="c"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    height: 100px;
}
.a {
    width: 500px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.b {
    min-width: 400px;
    background: red;
    flex: 1;
}
.c {
    min-width: 400px;
    background: yellow;
    flex: 1;
}
```

Chrome:
[image]

Safari:
[image]

Comment: It seems like it doesn't work like that.

Comment: `flex-basis` doesn't work on Chrome either. It makes both `div` equal in size and on the same line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than `min-width` use `flex-basis` (with suitable vendor prefixes of course).

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
}
.a {
  width: 500px;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.b {
  flex: 1 0 400px;
  background: red;
}
.c {
  background: yellow;
  flex: 1 0 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="c"></div>
</div>
```